# Numpy multidimensional slice

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

If a have a 2d Numpy array:

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

and I wanted to slice each row up to and including the first index position equal to 1, as below:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1],
       [0, 0, 1,
       [0, 0, 1])
```

Is it possible to achieve this using broadcasting, or must all output arrays have the same shape? I have a solution using the following, but I was curious if this could be achieved using broadcasting?

```
x = np.random.choice([0,1], size = [5,10])
idx = x.argmax(axis = 1) 

np.array([row[:i] for row, i in zip(x, idx + 1)])
```

Comment: Regular arrays can't have variable number of elements. So, `broadcasting` can't help directly for such an output.

Comment: As said a 2d numpy array has to have a fixed shape. I suggest using a list of numpy arrays.

Comment: @Divakar understood, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this use `dtype=object`

```
a =np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]]) 
idx = a.argmax(axis = 1) 
a = np.array([row[:i] for row, i in zip(a, idx + 1)], dtype=object)
```

The output is:

```
a = array([array([0, 1]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1]), array([1]),
       array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 0, 1])], dtype=object)
```